# link my users social media account in my mobile app, allowing native app to open

Tags: react-native, facebook, mobile, linker, expo

I've got an app with user profiles. On the users profile, I let them put links to their other social media accounts. I know app linking requires the correct app's schema and I know those schemas depend on the system (iOS, Android).  I want the user to be able to just copy the url of their social media profile (http://www.whateversocialmedia.com/userprofile),paste it and save it. I will manipulate the string get the "userprofile" out and put it in the schema.  HERE's the problem, Facebook, requires an ID for the schema, but most people don't know how to get their ID, while it's somewhat easy to get, it does require right clicking on a mouse and searching some code to get, Does Facebook have an api I can hit to send a username and get back a user ID? I feel like they would want people to link to their app easily. I've looked all over Graph API

Comment: No there is no API for that.

Comment: For future reference try narrowing down the scope of the question to make it easier for other users to answer. Place the most important elements first before sharing additional context. For example: "Is there an API to get a Facebook User ID? I am trying to allow users to link to their Facebook profile but it is inconvenient to look up the user ID by themselves"